# Assigning State to a table td

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My goal is to create a child component with a 5x5 grid and assign numbers to the grid based upon their state, f.e (4,5) would display on the 5th row of the 4th column with multiple numbers being rendered into the cells.

I'm unsure how to achieve in react as with jQuery I would target the ID of the td and append to the innerhtml.

I could map the array and create the html based if they meet a ternary operator however with a 5x5 grid this is going to get out of hand and messy quickly.

My html is structured as below

```
<table className={styles.HeatMapTable}>
      <thead />
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td className={styles.HeatMapYMarginLegend}>5</td>
          <td className={styles.HeatMapAmberCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapAmberCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td className={styles.HeatMapYMarginLegend}>4</td>
          <td className={styles.HeatMapGreenCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapAmberCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td className={styles.HeatMapYMarginLegend}>3</td>
          <td className={styles.HeatMapGreenCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapAmberCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapAmberCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td className={styles.HeatMapYMarginLegend}>2</td>
          <td className={styles.HeatMapGreenCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapGreenCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapAmberCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapAmberCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td className={styles.HeatMapYMarginLegend}>1</td>
          <td className={styles.HeatMapGreenCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapGreenCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapGreenCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapGreenCell} />
          <td className={styles.HeatMapAmberCell} />
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td />
          <td>1</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>5</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Edit; Parent Component

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDom from "react-dom";
import styles from "./Reporting.module.scss";
import { RiskReportProps } from "./RiskReportProps";
import { RiskReportState } from "./RiskReportState";
import { escape } from "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset";
import {
  SPHttpClient,
  SPHttpClientResponse,
  ISPHttpClientOptions
} from "@microsoft/sp-http";
import { RiskReportHeatMap } from "./RiskReportHeatMap";
import { RiskReportSummary } from "./RiskReportSummary";

export class RiskReport extends React.Component<
  RiskReportProps,
  RiskReportState
> {
  public static defaultProps: Partial<RiskReportProps> = {};

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      riskData: []
    };
  }

  public componentDidMount() {
    const url: string =
      this.props.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl +
      "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Risks')/items?$expand=RiskOwner&$select=Id,RiskID,RiskTheme,Risk,ResidualOveralLikelihood,ResidualSafety,ResidualSecurity," +
      "ResidualEnviroment,ResidualFinance,ResidualOperational,ResidualLegal,ResidualReputation,RiskVelocity,RiskOwner/Title";
    this.props.context.spHttpClient
      .get(url, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
      .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        response.json().then(data => {
          console.log(data.value);
          let riskTableData = [];
          data.value.forEach(c => {
            let risk = {
              riskID: "",
              riskTheme: "",
              risk: "",
              riskOwner: "",
              riskLikelihood: 0,
              riskConsequence: 0,
              riskVelocity: ""
            };
            risk.riskID = c.RiskID;
            risk.riskLikelihood = c.ResidualOveralLikelihood;
            risk.riskConsequence = Math.max(
              c.ResidualSafety,
              c.ResidualSecurity,
              c.ResidualEnviroment,
              c.ResidualFinance,
              c.ResidualOperational,
              c.ResidualLegal,
              c.ResidualReputation
            );
            risk.riskVelocity = c.RiskVelocity;
            risk.riskTheme = c.RiskTheme;
            risk.risk = c.Risk;
            risk.riskOwner = c.RiskOwner;
            riskTableData.push(risk);
          });
          console.log(riskTableData);
          this.setState(prevState => ({
            riskData: riskTableData
          }));
        });
      });
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<RiskReportProps> {
    return (
      <div className="riskReport">
        Reporting
        <RiskReportHeatMap riskData={this.state.riskData} />
        <RiskReportSummary riskData={this.state.riskData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Child component;

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDom from "react-dom";
import styles from "./Reporting.module.scss";
import { RiskReportHeatMapProps } from "./RiskReportHeatMapProps";
import { RiskReportHeatMapState } from "./RiskReportHeatMapState";
import { escape } from "@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset";

export class RiskReportHeatMap extends React.Component<
  RiskReportHeatMapProps,
  RiskReportHeatMapState
> {
  public static defaultProps: Partial<RiskReportHeatMapProps> = {};

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  private handleChange(event): void {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  public render(): React.ReactElement<RiskReportHeatMapProps> {
    return (
      <div className={styles.HeatMap}>
        Risk Report Heatmap<br />
        <br />
        <table className={styles.HeatMapTable}>
          <thead />
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td className={styles.HeatMapYMarginLegend}>5</td>
              <td className={styles.HeatMapAmberCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapAmberCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className={styles.HeatMapYMarginLegend}>4</td>
              <td className={styles.HeatMapGreenCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapAmberCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className={styles.HeatMapYMarginLegend}>3</td>
              <td className={styles.HeatMapGreenCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapAmberCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapAmberCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className={styles.HeatMapYMarginLegend}>2</td>
              <td className={styles.HeatMapGreenCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapGreenCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapAmberCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapAmberCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapRedCell} />
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td className={styles.HeatMapYMarginLegend}>1</td>
              <td className={styles.HeatMapGreenCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapGreenCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapGreenCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapGreenCell} />
              <td className={styles.HeatMapAmberCell} />
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td />
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
              <td>3</td>
              <td>4</td>
              <td>5</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

From the parent I'm passing the riskData object which contains likelihood which is the y axis I wish to plot and consequence is my x axis. There may be upto 20 numbers to plot on the table.

Comment: How is your state defined? Please add the whole component and any other relevant code with what you've tried so far

Comment: @SrThompson I have edited my question to show my parent and child component, the riskData object I'm passing I'm using to map, likelihood is the y axis and consequence is the x axis

Answer (score 0):

If each `riskData` contains the x-axis and y-axis data, you can separate them and then map over them. If I understood your question correctly, you can do something like this:

```
const riskData = [
  {
    riskID: "1",
    riskTheme: "",
    risk: "",
    riskOwner: "",
    riskLikelihood: 10,
    riskConsequence: 10,
    riskVelocity: ""
  },
  {
    riskID: "2",
    riskTheme: "",
    risk: "",
    riskOwner: "",
    riskLikelihood: 20,
    riskConsequence: 20,
    riskVelocity: ""
  } //etc
]

const xAxis = riskData.map(risk => ({ id: risk.riskID, consequence: risk.riskConsequence }));
const yAxis = riskData.map(risk => ({ id: risk.riskID, likelihood: risk.riskLikelihood }));

//I omitted most of your styles for brevity
const YourTable = () => (
  <div className={styles.HeatMap}>
    Risk Report Heatmap<br />
    <br />
    <table className={styles.HeatMapTable}>
      <thead />
      <tbody>
        {xAxis.map((xRisk, index) => (
          <tr key={xRisk.id}>
            <td>{index + 1}</td>
            {yAxis.map(yRisk => 
              <td key={yRisk.id}>
                L: {yRisk.likelihood}, C: {xRisk.consequence}
              </td>
            )}
          </tr>
        ))}
        <tr>
          <td />
          {riskData.map((r, i) => <td>{i + 1}</td>)}
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: This looks promising, I'll give it a try over the weekend. :)